# Does KMail stores emails encrypted at rest?

Tags: kde, security, kmail, kde-apps, akonadi

I would like to know if someone with access to my computer can read my emails and get my email provider password.

Comment: In what way is that related to a problem with Ubuntu?

Comment: @David Provided the OP uses Kmail on Ubuntu, the question is related in every way to Ubuntu and is definitelly on topic.

Comment: I guess we can agree to disagree I do not see it that way, read the question.

Comment: @David This is a topic that has been discussed a million times on the meta site and there exists consensus now that these questions are on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not opted out, on Kubuntu kmail uses kwallet to store your passwords. These are stored encrypted and are as safe as anything can be from someone with physical access to your computer.

Emails are not stored encrypted.